# Raise an error for an unsupported platform

Tags: msbuild

I'm creating a custom MSBuild script that is intended to be `Import`ed into multiple C# projects. The script adds several properties, references, and files to copy based on the `Platform` property to enable the final output to leverage a set of native binaries. In other words, it chooses the correct set of native binaries and the associated data based on the platform.

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
  <bin1>..\..\lib\mybinaries\x86\bin1.dll</bin1>
  <bin2>..\..\lib\mybinaries\x86\bin2.dll</bin2>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
  <bin1>..\..\lib\mybinaries\x64\bin1.dll</bin1>
  <bin2>..\..\lib\mybinaries\x64\bin2.dll</bin2>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="bin2.dll">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
    <HintPath>$(bin2)</HintPath>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="$(bin1)">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

When a project is built with an unsupport platform (such as Any CPU), I want the build to raise an error. How can I do this?

I looked into seeing if there's a way to raise an error outside of a build target, but I wasn't able to find one. Even if I did find one, I'd be worried about what would happen if a developer somehow got their system to pick an unsupported platform. (Such as Visual Studio might start refusing to open the project.)

I could override the `BeforeBuild` target, but this breaks down if the C# project importing this file then overrides that target itself. (Or mine would override theirs, depending on the order of `Import` and `<Target Name="BeforeBuild">`.) In that case, no error would be raised. This makes it rather fragile and not very robust.

How can I achieve this in such a way that the user is unlikely to break it? Or is there a completely different alternative approach I could look into for including the binaries conditionally?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like `<Target Name="MyPlatformCheck" BeforeTargets="Build"/>`? That would run before the build and uses builtin msbuild functionality and a custom name so is harder to override. There might be better targets to use e.g. 'PrepareBuild' or so but I don't know those from the top of my head..

Comment: @stijn I didn't realize it was possible to make Build depend on a custom task that way. If you could turn that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idiomatic way is to either use the `BeforeTargets` attribute of the [`Target` element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka.aspx), or to use the `InitialTargets` attribute of the [`Project` element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcxfsh87.aspx). So you write a custom target with all the logic needed and then have it called automatically. This also makes it hard for users to break it.

If you use BeforeTargets you'll want to find a target which gets called early in the build and preferrably for both Build and Clean. To figure out what to use the easiest is to build your project with diagnostic logging (`msbuild /v:d myproject` on the commandline). Then you'll see you're not the only one wanting to check for platform validity: the first target called for C++ projects is Microsoft's own _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform. So if you use

```
<Target Name="PlatformCheck" BeforeTargets="_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform">
  <Error Text="Bad Platform" Condition="'$(bin1)' == ''"/>
</Target>
```

then PlatformCheck will be one of the very first targets called.

Or if you prefer the other way, then it's

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="..." InitialTargets="PlatformCheck">
```

Comment: The task list for newer versions of MSBuild can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task-reference. I ended up using `AssignProjectConfiguration`. Trying to depend on `Build` was too late in the process; you'd get missing DLL errors before that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Target with an Error task. But if you want to avoid having a custom Target, you can use a dirty trick to cause the build to break through a property, if you just define a path that is sure to fail.

It would be something like that:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
  <bin1>..\..\lib\mybinaries\x86\bin1.dll</bin1>
  <bin2>..\..\lib\mybinaries\x86\bin2.dll</bin2>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
  <bin1>..\..\lib\mybinaries\x64\bin1.dll</bin1>
  <bin2>..\..\lib\mybinaries\x64\bin2.dll</bin2>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(bin1)' == ''">
  <bin1>ERROR: platform '$(Platform)' is not supported, please set it to x86 or x64</bin1>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The build will fail because this is not a valid path, and while the build log will be confusing, it will contain this clear message inside of the file-not-found one. :)

Again, I'd recommend defining a Target...